# Reference work for FF-Neural networks with back-propagation

Tags: neural-network, feed-forward

I know this is off-topic, please just either answer the question or redirect me to the right place to ask, i will close this question immediately afterwards.

**But what paper would be best to cite on the basic structure of a layered-feed-forward-neural-network with backpropagation?**

Is this applicable? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/329294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

D. E. Rumelhart, G. E. Hinton, and R. J. Williams, “Learning representation by backpropagating errors,” Nature, vol. 323, pp. 533–536, 1986